# Is the function $G$ right continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

> Suppose $S\subset\mathbb R$ such that $S\cap(x,\infty)\neq\phi$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$ and suppose that $g:S\to\mathbb R$ is a non-decreasing bounded function. Define $G:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ as: $$G(x)=\inf_{y\in S\cap(x,\infty)}g(y)$$for any $x\in\mathbb R$.
>
> Is the function $G$ right continuous?

I observe that $G$ is non-decreasing. Somehow I believe that it is not true that $G$ is right continuous. But I cannot really prove it. I suppose the reason why I believe this is that to say that $G$ is right continuous, I would need $g$ to be right continuous, which is not given. Again, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, note that for every decreasing sequence $x_n \to x$ you have $\bigcup_n (x_n,\infty) = (x,\infty)$. This implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{S\cap(x_n,\infty)} g =\inf_n \inf_{S\cap(x_n,\infty)} g = \inf_{S\cap(x,\infty)}g$. Since you have in general $\inf \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i = \inf_{i\in I} \inf A_i$

Comment: You seem to use a very powerful result that yields the answer as shown by you in one step! In reality, it is not so easy for me!! I will try to prove your result and try to see what you did, step by step.

Comment: You can easily show the last result for subsets of the reals. You only need to show that $\inf_{i \in I} \inf A_i$ is a lower bound for $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ and that every greater number is not. It is not that hard, if you like, I can show you!

Comment: Did you know this lemma or did you invent it? If you invented it, well, I must say you are great! I am trying to solve the main problem without using this lemma. Let's see how much I can proceed. :)

Comment: It's all a question of practice.